# Optimize find -exec {} with multiple conditions : specific files in a dir and specific subdirectories in this dir

Tags: shell-script, find, mp3, flac, synology

#### My problem is related to music encoding on my NAS and optimisation of linux `find` command.

I have write a script that is totally functionnal but I am sure this not the best way.

To summarize:

#### 1/ Script checks for directories that contain flac to encode

- all directories containing some `.flac` files
- the directories NOT containing a subdirectory named `mp3/` or `Mp3/`

For that specific part I have done something like this :

```
FILE="./DirContaininfFlacToConvertToMp3.txt"
find . -type f -iname '*.flac' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u > fic1
find . -iname 'mp3' -type d | sort | sed 's/\/Mp3//' | sed 's/\/mp3//' > fic2
comm -3 fic1 fic2 > $FILE
```

- The $FILE will be filled with all the directories matching these 2 conditions.
- `fic1` file contains all directories containing flac files.
- `fic2` file contains all directories containing mp3 subdir (sed is used to eliminate `mp3/` or `Mp3/` at the end of the path for the comm command to work)
- `comm -3` provide me my result in `$FILE`

It works all right but I am pretty sure this is not the best way to do and it can be optimized just using find parameters or passing it to shell ..

#### 2/ Script Encodes the flac files and move to a Mp3/ subdir

Once the file (`$FILE`) give the result of the directory that match the conditions next steps I do these:

- I encode the files in `mp3` in the defined directory
- I move them to a subdirectory named `Mp3` (keeping original structure)

For that part I done that in 2 loops:

```
#1st loop to encode
IFS=$'\n'
for next in `cat $FILE`
do
  find $next -type f  -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -qscale:a 2 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 {}.mp3 \;
done

#2nd loop for moving to subdir
for next in `cat $FILE`
do
  find $next -type f -name '*.flac.mp3' -execdir mkdir -p Mp3 \; -execdir mv {} Mp3/ \;
done
```

Also here I am pretty sure I could avoid iterating in 2 loops.

However you could find for any purpose the full script here (not very well coded I know ... :-(

#### Full script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Convert .flac en .mp3 file for Synology with ffmpeg
# usage : 1st construct list of directory to convert : run:  ./script.sh V
#         2nd verify and to convert run : nohup ./script C & 

#result of list of directories to encode
FILE="./ToConvertToMp3.txt"

# parameter validation
if [ "$#" -ne  "1" ]
  then
     echo "1 parameter required : ./script.sh (V)erify (C)onvert "
 exit 1;
fi


# generate list of directory for encoding
if [ "$1" ==  "V" ]
  then
    echo "-------- VERIFY AND CONSTRUCT LIST -------"
    #1 find dir that contains .flac file
    find . -type f -iname '*.flac' -printf '%h\n' | sort -u > fic1

    # for those directory search if there is some *mp3* subdir
    IFS=$'\n'
    for dirflac in `cat fic1`
    do
      find $dirflac -iname '*mp3*' -type d -exec dirname {} \; >> fic2
    done

    # sort and unicity
    cat fic2 | sort -u > fic3

    # final construc of the list of directory to encode
    comm -3 fic1 fic2 > $FILE
    rm -f fic1 fic2 fic3

    echo "-----DIRECTORY TO CONVERT-------"
    cat $FILE
    echo "-------------------------------------"
    exit 0
fi

# Converting .flav files from directories listed in $FILE
if [ "$1" ==  "C" ]
  then
    echo "-------- CONVERTING FLAC -------"

    if [ -e $FILE ]; then
      echo "$FILE exist : OK"
    else
      echo "$FILE does not exist Please (V)erification first"
    exit 3
    fi

  if [ -s "$FILE" ]; then
    echo "$FILE contains directories : OK"
    cat $FILE
  else
    echo "$FILE is empty , nothing to do"
    exit 2
  fi

  echo "-------- CONVERTING -------"
  IFS=$'\n'
  for next in `cat $FILE`
  do
    find $next -type f  -name "*.flac" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -qscale:a 2 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 {}.mp3 \;
    album="$(basename $directory)-Mp3";
    echo "  Processing $directory : creating subdirectory : $album, moving files in progress"
    find $directory -type f -name '*.flac.mp3' -execdir mkdir -p "$album" \; -execdir mv {} "$album/" \;

  done
  echo "-------- END OF CONVERSION -------"

  # renaming $FILE with timestamp
  ficdate=$(date +%Y%M%d-%Hh%m);
  mv $FILE $FILE-$ficdate.done;

  exit 0
fi

echo "WARNING : 1 parameter : usage : ./script.sh (V)erification (C)onversion"
```

Comment: Why are you not using `-printf '%h\n' | sort -u` for `fic2`? Note that you'd probably want `comm -23` as opposed to `comm -3`

Comment: Hello , I think for fic2 on my system the "-printf '%h\n' | sort -u" is not necessary because not like for fic1 where I do the find command on specific files for fic2 I am doing it on directory so with test I done I do not have any duplicated lines on this fic2 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -execdir sh -c '
  if [ ! -d mp3 ] && [ ! -d Mp3 ]; then
    for file do
      ffmpeg -i "$file" -qscale:a 2 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "${file%.*}.mp3"
    done
  fi' sh {} +
```

The idea being that with `-execdir cmd {} +`, (with some versions of GNU `find`), `find` will run `cmd` for all the matching file in a given directory.

I say *some versions of GNU find* because it used to work like that, but then was broken in some versions of `find` (where you'd get one `cmd` invocation per file as if you had used `-execdir cmd {} \;`) and it was fixed again in a later version.

You can check if you have a *correct* version with:

```
find . -execdir echo {} +
```

You should get one line per directory with a correct version, or one line per file with the less correct ones.

If you have a correct version, and provided you don't have thousands of flac files per directory, you can do both actions in one go:

```
find . -type f -name '*.flac' -execdir sh -c '
  if [ ! -d mp3 ] && [ ! -d Mp3 ]; then
    mkdir Mp3 || exit
    for file do
      ffmpeg -i "$file" -qscale:a 2 -map_metadata 0 -id3v2_version 3 "Mp3/${file%.*}.mp3"
    done
  fi' sh {} +
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. the First bloc of code is functionnal for me ;-) However on my system the `code` find . -execdir echo {} + `code` gave me one line per files so I do not have a correct version of find.  Thanks again